# SmartGWT 3.0 with Maven

Tags: maven, smartgwt

I couldn't find the SmartGWT 3.0 entry for maven.
For 2.4, I found below link:
http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/wiki/NightlyBuilds_and_MavenRepository

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried: http://www.smartclient.com/maven2/com/smartgwt/smartgwt/3.0/smartgwt-3.0.pom ?

Repository: http://www.smartclient.com/maven2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. That would do. But I am facing another problem now. We are using a local nexus mirror and when I add above dependency, it is saying "Failure to find com.smartgwt:smartgwt:jar:3.0". What do I need to do here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with nexus. I use artifactory. What I see on root there is no index files or any.

Comment: Yeeeeeeah! Thanks a lot for this answer!!!! I have been trying to get the repository files for smartGWT-4.0 for more than 18 hours and now I am sorted thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

I do realize this questions is about `SmartGWT 3.0` but I ended up here looking for maven dependency setup for `SmartGWT 4.0` and since this is the current stable version it may be worth sharing. This is the repositories/dependencies setup that works for me:

```
<repositories>
    <!-- other repositories -->
    <repository>
        <id>smartgwt</id>
        <url>http://www.smartclient.com/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!-- other dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <groupId>com.googlecode.smartgwt-maven-plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>smartgwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
```